# Is it OK to have only bidirectional relationships with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework

So the question is pretty much in the title.

Let's say I have some classe: User, Post, Comment and Tag.

- User has a @OneToMany List and
  @OneToMany List.
- Post has
  @ManyToOne User, @OneToMany
  List, @ManyToMany List.
- Comment has @ManyToOne List,
  @ManyToOne User.
- Tag has @ManyToMany
  List.

I'm new to Hibernate, but I find it easy then to use for example the attributes of a Tag object to get all the Post objects related to that tag, or find the author of a Post object or all the Post written by a certain User.

Is it OK ?

I'm talking more in terms of performance here. I'm also using the Play! framework. I don't know if this changes anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think some of them should be unidirectional.

For example, in real-world scenario you usually don't need to display "all `Post`s by `User`", because they should be filtered or paginatied, so you need to run queries against the database instead of retrieving `Post`s from the `User` (because not filtering a collection at the database side in these use cases can be a real performance problem, especially if that collection is huge).

Therefore having collection of `Post`s in `User` makes no sense. The same is true for `User` - `Comment` and `Tag` - `Post` relationships.

Comment: So what do I do I want to have a page that contains all the posts tagged with a particular tag?

Comment: @Marc: Execute a query like `SELECT p FROM Posts p WHERE :tag is member of p.tags`. And don't forget to apply `setFirstResult`/`setMaxResults`, because if your database is big you definitely dont' want to see a page with all matching posts.

Comment: But what is the point if I can just do for example `aTagObject.getPosts()`. It's because I cannot set `setFirstResult` and `setMaxResults`?

Comment: @Marc: Yes. If you have many `Post`s tagged with the certain tag, you don't need to display all of them at once. And if you have really many `Post`s, loading all of them into memory can cause performance problems.

Answer (score 2):

It is ok to have bidirectional relationships.  The real danger is in also having lazy false, because then you will end up loading a lot of your db into memory for every request.

If you have bidirectional relationships, it is good practice to create specific dao methods that allow you to load only the data you need, with hql.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you explain what is lazy false?

Comment: Oh I think I got it. Lazy means that it will only get the data from the database when you want to access the data? And when it is turned off, Hibernate will go get all the data it needs, so with bidirectionnal relationships you will end up loading a lot of your memory like you said? Assuming it is turned on, it is OK then?

Comment: You got it. Added another sentenc to my answer.